# How do I replace values in one dataset using values from another dataset in R?

Tags: r

So I have a data.frame called activity (pretty large dataset) that contains some NA values in the 'steps' column. I also have another dataset called avgstepsperday with the mean value of steps per day. I need to replace all the NA 'steps'values in activity with the corresponding mean 'steps' from avgstepsperday for that specific day. I am not sure how to do this.

Comment: You can create a logical vector to replace. `i1 <- is.na(activity$steps); activity$steps[i1] <- activity$avgstepsperday[i1]`

Answer (score 1):

As akrun mentioned, I will just put his code on an example such that you can visualize easier what happens. I hope it helps:

```
mat1<-matrix(c(1:12, NA, NA, NA),5,3) # Creating a matrix
colnames(mat1)<- c("A", "B", "C") # Adding colnames
dat1<-as.data.frame(mat1) # Passing it as dataframe
is.na(dat1) 
# A     B     C
# [1,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
# [2,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
# [3,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
# [4,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
# [5,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
dat1[is.na(dat1)] <- mean(dat1$C, na.rm = T) # Writing the mean of the same column

# A  B    C
# 1 1  6 11.0
# 2 2  7 12.0
# 3 3  8 11.5
# 4 4  9 11.5
# 5 5 10 11.5
```